# Reactive File Controller with Custom response headers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am building a File Controller that utilizes [zero-copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy) NIO functionality using Spring Boot 2.0 Spring Webflux. I also want to send custom response headers (for response caching, etc)

The code looks like below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class FileController {

 @GetMapping(value = "/{fileName:.+}")
    public Mono<ServerResponse> getFile(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {
        Resource body = new ClassPathResource(fileName);
        return ServerResponse.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, String.format("inline; filename=\"%s\"", fileName))
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(body));
    }

}
```

But when I execute the request from browser, I get the below error ins server logs:

```
2018-07-23 12:07:53.928 ERROR 9772 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : Unhandled failure: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerResponseBuilder$BodyInserterResponse]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerResponseBuilder$BodyInserterResponse and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS), response already set (status=null)
2018-07-23 12:07:53.928  WARN 9772 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : Handling completed with error: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerResponseBuilder$BodyInserterResponse]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerResponseBuilder$BodyInserterResponse and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

I don't know whats going wrong here. If I return `Mono<Resource>` from the controller method, then everything works fine but then I loose flexibility of providing customer response headers.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServerResponse` should be used with Spring WebFlux functional only - for this use case with the annotation model, `ResponseEntity` is the proper choice.

Because the WebFlux annotation model doesn't recognize the `ServerResponse` type, it is assuming it should serialize it (here, with Jackson).

Comment: So would it work with route based configuration? or ServerResponse will not work at all with FileSystemResource?

Comment: For this use case, `ResponseEntity` works with annotations https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-controller and `ServerResponse` works with the functional model https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn